# How would I set a string variable and pass it into a File reader scanner as a file name?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, ioexception

I am writing a Cipher program which asks the user for a file name, stores the name as a variable, and is then supposed to read the file based on the String variable. It compiles, but I keep getting an IOException when I try to run it.

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException:  (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
 at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
 at Cipher.main(Cipher.java:22)
```

I don't understand what is happening. It gives the error before the user has a change to type the file name. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Cipher {

public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String inFile = "";

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Welcome to Caeser Cipher");
            System.out.println("Enter 1 to encipher, or 2 to decipher (-1 to exit): ");
            int cipher = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("What non-negative shift should I use?");
            int shift = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("What is the input file name?");
            inFile = sc.nextLine();
            try {

                Scanner input = new Scanner (new FileReader (inFile) ) ;
                String line = input.nextLine();



       /* System.out.println("What is the output file name?");
         String outFile = sc.nextLine();*/

        Scanner input = new Scanner (new FileReader (inFile) ) ;
        input.useDelimiter("['.!?0-9+");

        String line = input.nextLine();

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {

                line = input.nextLine();

                if (cipher == 1) {
                    System.out.println(caeserEncipher(line, shift));
                } else if (cipher == 2) {
                    System.out.println(caeserDecipher(line, shift));
                } else {
                    System.out.println ("Enter 1 to encipher, or 2 to decipher (-1 to exit)");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println ("Trouble opening or reading the file...");
            System.out.println ("Perhaps it was misspelled!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

   public static String caeserEncipher(String input, int shift) {
        int arr[] = new int[input.length()];
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int length = input.length();
        String output = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            arr[i] = (int) input.charAt(i);
            arr[i] += shift;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            builder.append((char)arr[i]);
        }

        output = builder.toString();
        return output;

}

public static String caeserDecipher(String input, int shift) {
int arr[] = new int[input.length()];
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
int length = input.length();
String output = "";

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    arr[i] = (int) input.charAt(i);
    arr[i] -= shift;
}

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    builder.append((char)arr[i]);
}

output = builder.toString();
return output;

    }

}
```

Comment: If you intput the filename do you write only `file.txt` or the path of the file?

Comment: you would input file.txt

Comment: I was just asking whats your Input because I think you Need to Input the path of the file only the filename is not enough

Comment: I'm using cloud9 so you don't need to input the file path as long as the file is in the same folder you're working in

Comment: You should post the the stacktrace of the IOException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with your code

you are directly calling `scanner.nextLine()` after `scanner.nextInt()` is called .

In this scenario if you input say `5` for `nextInt()` and press enter, then it would return `5 for`scanner.nextInt()`and`new line`for`scanner.nextLine()`. This occurs because`scanner.nextInt()`doesn't consume the last newline leading to`nextLine`having`newline`. So, in your case, user will not get a chance to input the file-name leading to error and it would seem that`scanner.nextLine()` call is skipped.

So before calling `scanner.nextLine()`, add another `scanner.nextLine()` above it just to consume the last new line.

As far as the file name is concerned, run your program with absolute path and it should run fine: like `D:\Work\file.txt`

Comment: I'm using cloud9, so I don't need to input the file path as long as the file is in the same folder I'm working in

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many mistakes.

1. Multiple time declaration of `input`,`line`.
2. wrong regular expression. `"['.!?0-9+"` should be `"\\['.!?0-9+"`.
3. Un managed newline (<kbd>Enter</kbd>) after `scanner.nextLine()` .

Try this modified code :-

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Cipher {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String inFile = "";

        // avoiding multtiple delcaration.
        Scanner input = null;
        String line = "";

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Caeser Cipher");
        System.out.println("Enter 1 to encipher, or 2 to decipher (-1 to exit): ");
        int cipher = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("What non-negative shift should I use?");
        int shift = sc.nextInt();

        sc.nextLine(); // clearing '\n' (newline)
        System.out.println("What is the input file name?");
        inFile = sc.nextLine();
        try {

            input = new Scanner(new FileReader(inFile));
            line = input.nextLine();

            /*
             * System.out.println("What is the output file name?"); String outFile =
             * sc.nextLine();
             */

            input = new Scanner(new FileReader(inFile));
            input.useDelimiter("\\['.!?0-9+");            // changed reg-expression

            line = input.nextLine();

            while (input.hasNextLine()) {

                line = input.nextLine();

                if (cipher == 1) {
                    System.out.println(caeserEncipher(line, shift));
                } else if (cipher == 2) {
                    System.out.println(caeserDecipher(line, shift));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Enter 1 to encipher, or 2 to decipher (-1 to exit)");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Trouble opening or reading the file...");
            System.out.println("Perhaps it was misspelled!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String caeserEncipher(String input, int shift) {
        int arr[] = new int[input.length()];
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int length = input.length();
        String output = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            arr[i] = (int) input.charAt(i);
            arr[i] += shift;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            builder.append((char) arr[i]);
        }

        output = builder.toString();
        return output;

    }

    public static String caeserDecipher(String input, int shift) {
        int arr[] = new int[input.length()];
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int length = input.length();
        String output = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            arr[i] = (int) input.charAt(i);
            arr[i] -= shift;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            builder.append((char) arr[i]);
        }

        output = builder.toString();
        return output;

    }

}
```